# submenu won't show on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tested on a Mac in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but the submenu in this page is not showing on hover:

http://www.mickyvanhouten.nl

Can anyone tell me what is happening? The submenu is there and as far as I can tell should be visible, but it is not.

Thanx!

Comment: you should show some code and explain your issue a bit.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or some other [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: To be honest, linking the demo is better than partial code fragments here or a fiddle.. The issue is quite clear, the submenus are not showing, you can remove their "display:none" and they still won't be seen anywhere in the page.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov Do you mean to understand a 'non english website' demo?

Comment: @Mark you don't need to understand the page to actually understand what is the submenu. It's obvious where the nav is and when you inspect it you can easily navigate in the markup, which is.. in english.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov you are right, I dont need english to understand what is submenu, but once I see its not english, I will close it right away because stackoverflow should be in english. Then I praise you to take your time to inspect his code 1 by 1, to get his submenu codes and problems

Comment: `stackoverflow should be in english` ← His question is in english tho..  I don't mean to meddle but, I don't think the language of his website matters when all of our codes are in english.. Since his demo is a verifiable example I think it is much better than fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It #left-col-fix, this is set to overflow-y: sroll - but the parent #header is set to 300px, so the submenu is showing, but with a left margin of 300px it doesn't show within the parent.

Change overflow-y to "visible" to fix the problem, just so:

```
#left-col-fix {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 3001;
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: visible;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```